# PHP - How to write image resource to file

Tags: php, gd

I used function `imagecopyresampled` to cropping image.

I tried use `file_put_contents` and fwrite to write the resized_image to file on hard disk but all attempts were failed.

Can I write the resized image to disk instead of using `imagejpg` to print it out to browser?

Comment: Have you tried imagick? Check it out here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Here's the function signature for [imagejpeg()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagejpeg.php):

```
bool imagejpeg ( resource $image [, string $filename [, int $quality ]] )
```

So, provide your destination filename as the second argument. (Standard filesystem permission warnings apply, make sure the process has write access to that directory.)