# Laravel, file storage put php resource

Tags: laravel, laravel-filesystem

I was reading [Laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/filesystem#storing-files), and came across the following example which I didn't quite understand:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;

Storage::put('file.jpg', $contents);

Storage::put('file.jpg', $resource);
```

I understand that the arg1 is the path of file or directory and the arg2 is the content to be written into file or file to be saved into directory. However, I don't quite understand the PHP resource here. Is there anything I could use the PHP recourse on a jpg file? Or the document actually means that I could save a PHP resource into the directory, but it just misplaced a jpg example instead of directory?

Anyone could help will be so much appreciated.

Comment: A resource can be a reference to an opened jpeg file. Maybe reading about resources would help you understand. https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.resource.php | check this as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8814364/php-how-to-write-image-resource-to-file

Comment: @user3532758 Hey! Thanks for your reply. I read the information you provided. Could you also make some examples in this case?